# Random characters in localhost project path URL

Tags: localhost, webstorm

Wondering why I'm noticing random characters in my localhost location URL when running projects from WebStorm?

As can be seen after cards.html in the below example:

localhost:63342/Project/cards.html?_ijt=puj3ee9ohel0mc7bdbclslh8t3

I can't recall observing this behaviour previously.

Is this a WebStorm configuration or something else I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done to fix the built-in web server CSRF vulnerability. Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/

Comment: Thank you! I'll assume this is normal behavior then.